# NEO M8T with RTKRCV on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi3

I am currently doing a university project and my goal is to find the position of a rover in real time.

My set up is the following: 2x NEO M8T boards connected to a Raspberry Pi 3 (updated to latest version GNU/Linux 8).

The reason that they are both connected to the Pi is that I am not sure that my SiK telemetry transmits anything as even in RTK Navi on a laptop I don't get base station data. (the radios are matched)

The M8Ts are set to 115000 baud rate by using u-center (latest version). NMEA messages are turned off and UBX messages are turned on.

I installed the latest version of RTKLIB from tomojitakasu's github on the Pi. Ran make in the rtkrcv folder.
Ran chmod +x rtkstart.sh and chmod +x rtkshut.sh as it wanted permissions.

Started rtkrcv with sudo ./rtkrcv

I get "invalid option value pos-1snrmask" but the program still runs.
I run a conf file which I created but I DONT KNOW if it is correct.

It says "startup script ok" "rtk server start error" and thats it... nothing else.
The conf file I use is as following:

```
# RTKRCV options for RTK (2014/10/24, tyan)

    console-passwd      =admin
    console-timetype        =gpst        # (0:gpst,1:utc,2:jst,3:tow)
    console-soltype     =dms         # (0:dms,1:deg,2:xyz,3:enu,4:pyl)
    console-solflag     =1           # (0:off,1:std+2:age/ratio/ns)
    ## Specify connection type for Rover (1), Base (2) and Correction (3) streams
    inpstr1-type        =serial    # (0:off,1:serial,2:file,3:tcpsvr,4:tcpcli,7:ntripcli,8:ftp,9:http)
    inpstr2-type        =serial    # (0:off,1:serial,2:file,3:tcpsvr,4:tcpcli,7:ntripcli,8:ftp,9:http)
    ##inpstr3-type      =serial    # (0:off,1:serial,2:file,3:tcpsvr,4:tcpcli,7:ntripcli,8:ftp,9:http)
    ## Specify connection parameters for each stream
    inpstr1-path        = ttyACM0:115200:8n:1off
    inpstr2-path        = ttyACM1:115200:8n:1off
    ##inpstr3-path      =
    ## Specify data format for each stream
    inpstr1-format      =ubx       # (0:rtcm2,1:rtcm3,2:oem4,3:oem3,4:ubx,5:ss2,6:hemis,7:skytraq,8:sp3)
    inpstr2-format      =ubx       # (0:rtcm2,1:rtcm3,2:oem4,3:oem3,4:ubx,5:ss2,6:hemis,7:skytraq,8:sp3)
    ##inpstr3-format        =       # (0:rtcm2,1:rtcm3,2:oem4,3:oem3,4:ubx,5:ss2,6:hemis,7:skytraq,8:sp3)
    ## Configure the NMEA string to send to get Base stream. Required for VRS.
    inpstr2-nmeareq     =off         # (0:off,1:latlon,2:single)
    inpstr2-nmealat     =0           # (deg)
    inpstr2-nmealon     =0           # (deg)
    ## Configure where to send the solutions
    outstr1-type        =off      # (0:off,1:serial,2:file,3:tcpsvr,4:tcpcli,6:ntripsvr)
    outstr2-type        =off         # (0:off,1:serial,2:file,3:tcpsvr,4:tcpcli,6:ntripsvr)

    ## Specify here which stream contains the navigation message.
    misc-navmsgsel      =corr        # (0:all,1:rover,1:base,2:corr)
    misc-startcmd       =./rtkstart.sh
    misc-stopcmd        =./rtkshut.sh
    ## Set the command file to send prior to requesting stream (if required)
    file-cmdfile1       =/home/pi/rtklib/app/rtkrcv/gcc/m8t.cmd
    file-cmdfile2       =/home/pi/rtklib/app/rtkrcv/gcc/m8t.cmd
    ## file-cmdfile3        =
    pos1-posmode        =static  # (0:single,1:dgps,2:kinematic,3:static,4:movingbase,5:fixed,6:ppp-kine,7:ppp-static)
    pos1-frequency      =l1      # (1:l1,2:l1+l2,3:l1+l2+l5)
    pos1-soltype        =forward     # (0:forward,1:backward,2:combined)
    pos1-elmask     =15          # (deg)
    pos1-snrmask_L1     =0           # (dBHz)
    pos1-dynamics       =off         # (0:off,1:on)
    pos1-tidecorr       =off         # (0:off,1:on)
    pos1-ionoopt        =brdc        # (0:off,1:brdc,2:sbas,3:dual-freq,4:est-stec)
    pos1-tropopt        =saas        # (0:off,1:saas,2:sbas,3:est-ztd,4:est-ztdgrad)
    pos1-sateph     =brdc        # (0:brdc,1:precise,2:brdc+sbas,3:brdc+ssrapc,4:brdc+ssrcom)
    pos1-exclsats       =            # (prn ...)
    ## Set which GNSS to use. 1 is GPS only, 4 is GLONASS only. Add codes for multiple systems. Eg. (1+4)=5 is GPS+GLONASS.
    pos1-navsys     =7         # (1:gps+2:sbas+4:glo+8:gal+16:qzs+32:comp)
    ## Ambiguity Resolution mode, set to continuous to obtain fixed solutions
    pos2-armode     =fix-and-hold  # (0:off,1:continuous,2:instantaneous,3:fix-and-hold)
    pos2-gloarmode      =off         # (0:off,1:on,2:autocal)
    pos2-arthres        =3
    pos2-arlockcnt      =0
    pos2-arelmask       =0           # (deg)
    pos2-aroutcnt       =5
    pos2-arminfix       =10
    pos2-slipthres      =0.05        # (m)
    pos2-maxage     =30          # (s)
    pos2-rejionno       =30          # (m)
    pos2-niter          =1
    pos2-baselen        =0           # (m)
    pos2-basesig        =0           # (m)
    out-solformat       =llh         # (0:llh,1:xyz,2:enu,3:nmea)
    out-outhead     =on          # (0:off,1:on)
    out-outopt          =off         # (0:off,1:on)
    out-timesys     =gpst        # (0:gpst,1:utc,2:jst)
    out-timeform        =tow         # (0:tow,1:hms)
    out-timendec        =3
    out-degform     =deg         # (0:deg,1:dms)
    out-fieldsep        =
    out-height          =ellipsoidal # (0:ellipsoidal,1:geodetic)
    out-geoid           =internal    # (0:internal,1:egm96,2:egm08_2.5,3:egm08_1,4:gsi2000)
    out-solstatic       =all         # (0:all,1:single)
    out-nmeaintv1       =0           # (s)
    out-nmeaintv2       =0           # (s)
    out-outstat     =off         # (0:off,1:state,2:residual)
    stats-errratio      =100
    stats-errphase      =0.003       # (m)
    stats-errphaseel        =0.003       # (m)
    stats-errphasebl        =0           # (m/10km)
    stats-errdoppler        =1           # (Hz)
    stats-stdbias       =30          # (m)
    stats-stdiono       =0.03        # (m)
    stats-stdtrop       =0.3         # (m)
    stats-prnaccelh     =1           # (m/s^2)
    stats-prnaccelv     =0.1         # (m/s^2)
    stats-prnbias       =0.0001      # (m)
    stats-prniono       =0.001       # (m)
    stats-prntrop       =0.0001      # (m)
    stats-clkstab       =5e-12       # (s/s)
    ant1-postype        =llh        # (0:llh,1:xyz,2:single,3:posfile,4:rinexhead,5:rtcm)
    ant1-pos1           =0           # (deg|m)
    ant1-pos2           =0           # (deg|m)
    ant1-pos3           =0           # (m|m)
    ant1-anttype        =
    ant1-antdele        =0           # (m)
    ant1-antdeln        =0           # (m)
ant1-antdelu

    =0           # (m)
```

Please, help!!
Regards
Arnaudov

Comment: Just a side note: the Pi is incapable of processing things in real time due to its kernel.

Comment: What do you mean? I have to post process the data? It's the first time someone to tell me that? :-)

Comment: and by the way I am Bulgarian as well, can you send me some contact details to discuss that if possible? :)

Comment: Hi. What I mean is that for real time processing you need a real time capable operating system. As far as I know there is a version of the Rasbian with a low latency kernel on the Internet but have forgotten where I saw it. For the contact details Stackoverflow doesn't offer tools to exchange such information hence there is no plausible way to do it.